# Chef vs. Puppet: Which works best on Joyent SmartMachines?

Tags: infrastructure

Currently we're planning to take our app to a dynamic infrastructure and we're caught between Chef and Puppet. Each has pros and cons but seeking community answer from anyone who has experience with this.

Given cost, robustness, and support, which is better suited for a Joyent SmartMachine/Solaris/SmartOS infrastructure?

Comment: What are the pros and cons from YOUR environment's perspective?

Answer (score 0):

Ben Rockwood of Joyent [stated](http://discuss.joyent.com/viewtopic.php?pid=232483#p232483) in November that both work quite well, with the caveat of ncsd fd leaks if running on Ruby 1.8.

So I second the advise of ewwhite to judge the two on their individual benefits.